# Поиск максимально быстрого алгоритма x86-64

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация, x86-64

Доброго времени суток,
Существует ли способ выявить логическим путём самый быстрый алгоритм решения задачи при программировании или область решения? Конечно звучит максимально абстрактно, но может быть хотя бы направление укажите?

Comment: похоже, Вам нужно почитать о [O](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: Если бы такой способ был, вопрос `P ?= NP` давно был бы решен.

Comment: Прочитайте статьи по теме "Оценка сложности алгоритмов"

Comment: Вот хороший вопрос по этой теме на английском stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm?rq=1